# Showing that closure of W, a subspace of a Hilbert space, is a subset of the double orthogonal complement of W

Tags: general-topology

Well, the question is basically in the title. It's easy enough to show that W itself must be a subset of the double orthogonal complement, but how would I go about showing that the closure of W is also a subset of the double orthogonal complement?

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ denote the ambient Hilbert space. Given $w \in W$, let $w^\flat \in X^*$ be the continuous linear functional defined by $w^\flat(x) = \langle x,w\rangle$ for $x \in X$. Since $w^\flat : X\to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous, $\ker(w^\flat)$ is a closed hyperplane in $X$ for all $w \in W$. Now, observe that $$W^\bot = \bigcap_{w \in W} \ker(w^\flat)$$
is an intersection of closed subspaces of $X$, and hence is closed, as well. Applying the same argument to $W^\bot$ in place of $W$, we deduce that $(W^\bot)^\bot$ is also closed. Since the closure $\overline W$of $W$ is contained in every closed subset of $X$ containing $W$, and $W \subset (W^\bot)^\bot$, we have $\overline{W} \subset (W^\bot)^\bot$.